# Compute occurrences of column data within a DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset and I retrieve it by

```
var ds = data.tables[0]
```

I want to find the number of occurrences of data in a particular row

```
Teams | Member
Boys  | John
Boys  | Dave
Girls | Sarah
```

so in the example set above I would like to get the number of occurrences of Boys.

Is this possible with the DataSets Compute function?

```
data.tables[0].Compute("...","...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
DataRow[] rows= ds.Select("Teams = 'Boys'");
Console.WriteLine(rows.Length.ToString())
```